# BNB not received in metamask. account hacked

Tags: binance-smart-chain

I send my funds from binance to metamask but they didn't arrive there, as soon as I made the transaction those funds were sent to this 0x9BaA07fE6fe645Bb29A53E064699d30Bd5c63e0E address.
.
please help me !!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not much you can do, your funds have already been transferred.

Looks like someone got your private key and has a bot listening to your address and transferring funds as soon as they arrive at this address.

Don't ever use this address again and figure out how you got your private key stolen and improve your security from it.

Hope this helps

Comment: How can I improve my security? By the way thanks for help

Comment: Well how did your keys get compromised? We’re you hack downloading a .exe file from a shady website? Did you store your private key on a cloud? Find how you got compromised and improve on that

Comment: Well I think I downloaded a pirated copy of trading view and after that my Instagram was also following some random people. Basically some one  from Brazil was accessing my Instagram. So now how to uninstall that shit from my pc or I have to reset my pc.